# No module named locals. Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Запускаю скрипт (.py):

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
pygame.display.set_caption('Fdd')
pygame.draw.line(window,(10,100,100),(10,200),(20,300),2)
pygame.display.flip()
while 1:

     for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == QUIT:
       sys.exit()
```

Вылетает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Pyt\tf.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "D:\Pyt\pygame.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pygame.locals import *
ImportError: No module named locals
```

Как я понял, ошибка в этом:

```
from pygame.locals import *
```

Но когда пишешь в Shell консоли, такой ошибки не возникает.

Может кто-нибудь помочь?

Answer (score 4):

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
```

А зачем Вы 2 раза одно и тоже импортируете? вам достаточно только

```
import pygame
```

А вообще интерпретатор ищет модули в этих папках

```
import sys
print("\n".join(sys.path))
```

и в текущей директории. Этот модуль должен лежать в одной из этих папок.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял вы файл, лежащий в той же директории, что и исполняемый назвали pygame.py В итоге в строке import pygame питон импортирует не библиотеку pygame, а файл pygame.py Не надо называть питоновские файлы разными ключевыми именами и названиями библиотек, а то произойдут ошибки.
  Из консоли такая ошибка не возникает потому-что рядом с ней уже нет файла с ключевым именем pygame.py и происходит стандартный импорт библиотеки pygame, что вам и надо